# Ordering Stylesheets in Wordpress Child theme breaks

Tags: wordpress

In parent theme the styles orders in this way - bootstrap.min, font-awesome, zzz-style.
When I active child theme, main style css jumps to the top and layout breaks.
zzz-style, bootstrap.min, font-awesome, zzz-child-style.

```
// enqueue the parent theme stylesheet

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('zzz-style',  get_stylesheet_uri());


// enqueue the child theme stylesheet

function zzz_child_scripts() {  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'zzz-child-style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css' );     
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zzz_child_scripts');
```

What is the best way order Stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_style` allows you to set dependencies for stylesheets that will help you determine load order. [Here are the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).

```
// enqueue the parent theme stylesheet

wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array('bootstrap'));
wp_enqueue_style('zzz-style',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('bootstrap'));


// enqueue the child theme stylesheet

function zzz_child_scripts() {  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'zzz-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('zzz-style') );     
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zzz_child_scripts');
```

On line 5 (where you include `zzz-style`), notice the `array('bootstrap')` argument. This tells WordPress to load `zzz-style` *after* `bootstrap`.

Note: CSS stylesheet ordering should not matter as much as abiding by proper [CSS cascading rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

Comment: Here is what happens when I change the code as you mentions:
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='http://dev.loc/wp-content/themes/zzz/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />`

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='zzz-style-css'  href='http://dev.loc/wp-content/themes/zzz-child/style.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />`

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='zzz-child-style-css'  href='http://dev.loc/wp-content/themes/zzz-child/style.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all' />`

Comment: @user3351236 when enqueuing the parent theme's stylesheet, try using `get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'`. I'll update my answer.